# CRM 2011:How to hide the ribbons according to security role using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

In my entity contains edit and information form,i want to hide the ribbons if the user does not have the particular security role.And will show both the forms if the user has security role

Comment: What do you mean by *hide*? Must it be hidden in such a way that the user would never be able to access the ribbon, or initially hidden with an option for the user to "unhide" it if he pleased?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this blog post can help you ["How To Use "CustomRule" to Enable/Disable HomePageGrid Buttons- CRM 2011"](http://howto-mscrm.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-series-6-how-to-use-customrule.html).